# What is the difference between creating a new modelandview or passing in a model as method parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got into the habit of doing this, so that in my unit tests I could check what had been added to model:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView goHome()
{
  ModelandView mav = new ModelAndView("foobar.jsp");
  mav.addObject("bar", new Bar());
  return mav;
}
```

Is this better:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goHome(final Model model)
{
  model.addAttribute("bar", new Bar());
  return "foobar.jsp";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is only semantic. If you do not create the `ModelAndView` object Spring will do it for you.

Generally the second approach is preferable since it's a lot easier to unit test, especially if you pass a `Map` instead of your model.

---

**EDIT** To clarify on testing (based on `jUnit`). I find the following signature preferable:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goHome(final Map model) {
    model.addAttribute("bar", new Bar());
    return "foobar.jsp";
}
```

This allows us to create a test without even knowing `Spring` is involved

```
@Test
public void testGoHome() {
    // Setup
    Controller controller = ...
    Map<String, Bar> model = new HashMap<String, Bar>();

    // Test
    assertEquals("foobar.jsp", controller.goHome(model));
    assertNotNull(model.get("bar"));
}
```

This example is based on a `Map`, but could also be a `ModelMap` or even `Model` if you preferred.

Comment: I remember now,  I did it becuase I though it was easier to unit test when you return a modelandview, how else do you test what has been added to model, if you just return a string ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky you can do mock Model object and pass it to the method

Comment: @NimChimksky, `Spring` tries to be *non-intrusive*. E.g., you take a regular non-spring aware method, annotated it with `Spring` annotations and all of a sudden it's web-enabled.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, in the controller, `Spring` creates the map for you. The  model has a `bar` in it because that's what the controller *puts* in it.

Comment: @NimChimpsky well, let's see, Model object can be constructed and populated in different ways: direct building new object, `@ModelAttribute`, `@SessionAttrubutes`, etc. So if do not use any specific tools for work with model, you can do direct create and check result. :)

Comment: @NimChimpsky it's a kind of design choice: what you need from your controllers, how they should work with model. And set of tools for different cases. So if you need to make a direct model creating  - just do it.